# Why is express appending object array names with "[]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with a Node.js/Express.js backend. On the front end I pass an object to my backend API this way.

```
var accountData = {"my_tags" : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]}
$.post("/api/submission/1", accountData, function(sucess){
      console.log("success");
    });
```

On the back end app.js is setup this way

```
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);
```

then in my api

```
router.post("/api/submission/:pageNumber", function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

prints {"my_tags[]": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]}

Why is Node or Express appending "[]" to the name of the "my_tags" object array?

Answer (score 0):

Of course forcing myself to write this up leads me to grok the answer 2 minutes later when I reread my post. It turns out to be because my url encoded body parser's extended attribute was set to false. Changing

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

in app.js to

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

stops appending "[]" to my array titles. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks! @jsalonoen, just learning express obviously and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that default content type for jQuery is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), which ends up getting handled by bodyParser. Setting it to JSON would allow you to parse it using `bodyParser.json()`.